# Complex Analysis and Heat Potential

Tags: complex-analysis, heat-equation

What does the imaginary part of the complex heat potential tell us ? I understand that the real part gives the temperature distribution and that, since we add the real and imaginary parts, the imaginary part will have the same units as temperature but what does it tell us?

Comment: Could you provide more context, such as what equation you are referring to?

Comment: F(z)= T(x,y) + iY(x,y). Where for a steady state heat flow problem, we have nabla^2(T), such that we can model a two dimensional steady heat flow problem by Laplace's equation